# unable to compare two float number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to match two float number but unable check below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mcsab3aa/2/

js code:

```
$('#checkButton').click(function() { 
    var getusertarget = parseFloat(jQuery("#targetval").val());
    var currentval = $("#demo").find( "h1" ).html();
    currentval = parseFloat(currentval.replace('$',''));
    console.log(currentval);
    console.log(getusertarget);
    var dividerval = (currentval/targetval);  // it should be 1
    console.log(dividerval);
    if (dividerval==1) {
        $('.coins_drags').hide();
        //$("#demo").find( "h1" ).html('$' + sum.toFixed(2) + '<br />Great job');
        console.log('great');
 }
    else { 
        //$("#demo").find( "h1" ).html('$' + sum.toFixed(2) + '<br />Try again');
        //sum = 0;
        console.log('try');
    }   

});
```

Comment: what is suppose to happen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mcsab3aa/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
var dividerval = (currentval/targetval);
```

targetval is undefined. You might want to do:

```
var dividerval = (currentval/getusertarget);
```

Comment: Not so much undefined as not defined. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var dividerval = (currentval/getusertarget);
```

instead of

```
var dividerval = (currentval/targetval);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/mcsab3aa/4/

```
var h1 = $("#demo").find( "h1" ),
    targetVal = f2num(h1.text()),
    current = $("#targetval"),
    msg = $('.msg');

msg.text('click after typing your guess');

$('#checkButton').click(function () {
    if (current.val() == targetVal) {
        msg.text('Great job');
        h1.html('$' + targetVal).show();
    } else {
        h1.hide();
        msg.text('try again!');
    }

});

function f2num(n) {
    return parseFloat((n+"").replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));
}
```

The problem was that you were trying to parse number with $ in it. And had handlers reversed.